# Texture is extremely desaturated exclusively in the texture paint tab

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, texture-paint-mode

I edited the uv coordinates of the model, and when I switched back to the texture paint tab the texture became extremely desaturated. I may have accidentally clicked an option I didn't intend to, but I have no idea what to look for.

This is how it looks in the texture paint tab.
[image: The spider in the texture paint viewport has an extremely light texture]

In the shading tab, as well as all others, the saturation is correct.
[image: A correctly saturated spider in the shading viewport.]

Comment: Hello could you please pack your image and share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/